# How can I change my profession?

Tags: fallen-london

My profession gives me weekly bonuses to my Persuasion skill, but it also mentions that if my Persuasion skill is above 70, it is time to choose a new profession. I am getting close to that point, so I figure I should think about changing my profession.

How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first step in changing your profession is leaving your current one.

You can make a resignation letter for yourself by following the "Choose a new Profession" Storylet located at your Lodgings (note that if you are resigning from an Advanced Profession, you will lose the unique item associated with it.):

[image: pic]

Once that is out of the way, you can then take up a new Training Profession or Advanced Profession.

Training Professions help improve your main qualities up to level 70. After that, you'll want something a little more advanced. It's a little out of the scope of this question to list the details of every possible profession, and there is already [a good article about it that you can go check out at the Echo Bazaar wiki](http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Profession).

To gain a new Training Profession, just use the "Adopt a Training Profession" Storylet that you can find at your Lodgings after quitting your old Profession.

Advanced Professions require you to have connections with certain factions, and opportunities to gain a new Advanced profession are only available through "Connected" type Opportunity cards.

If you don't want to wait for a certain Opportunity card to show up, you can spend some Fate on the "Arrange Favourable Circumstances" Storylet and use the resulting Favourable Circumstances to arrange a meeting with your contacts using the aptly named "Arrange a meeting with your contacts" Storylet.

Both of these storylets can be found at your Lodgings, under "Write Letters":

[image: pic2]

[image: pic3]

Comment: Don't forget that training professions look at your *buffed* stat. So unequip any boosting gear when picking up your weekly Earnest of Payment. Also, bringing a Talkative Rattus Faber (-25 to all stats) will let you level your stats with Earnests of Payment even when you're past 70.

Comment: @Yuuki is this still the case as of today?

Answer (score 0):

When you are in your lodgings, one of the activities is "Write a letter". (An option of?) this allows you to quit your profession.